# ClearRect is removing everything on the Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Trying to get this hover function working, but when I hover it clears the entire canvas. Can't figure out what the clearRect is clearing, and how I can focus it on only clearing the rectangle I've drawn in the statement. Any guidance - some of the canvas rendering simply depends on order in code.

```
function handleMouseMove(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      let mouseX = e.clientX - offsetX;
      let mouseY = e.clientY - offsetY;


      for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        let cx = t[i].Criticality * 100 + 50;
        let cy = t[i].Score + 50;
        var dx = mouseX - cx;
        var dy = mouseY - cy;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, dx, dy);
        if (dx * dx + dy * dy < 15 * 15) {
          draw();
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.fillStyle = "white";
          ctx.fillRect(mouseX, mouseY, 130, 70);
          ctx.stroke();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What do the `Criticality` and `Score` properties have to do with the `cx` and `cy` respectively? Also, this isn't the greatest practice, you should separate your logic (collision detection mainly) from the rendering, which you are doing after a collision.

Comment: @Ameer `cx` and `cy` are the plotted points on the graph. Criticality and score are user input but require manipulation to graph correctly.